# No module named 'pyspark.testing' when running CI/CD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have encountered the following error in my `azure-devops`.

```
    ImportError: Failed to import test module: databricks.test.unittest.test_spark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/databricks/test/unittest/test_spark.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pyspark.testing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.testing'
```

The error occurs when running our pipelines from `azure-pipelines.yml`. In there, I have the line:

```
- script: |
    export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$(pwd)
    pip install pyspark==3.4.1
    python -m unittest discover -s databricks/test/unittest -t .
  displayName:  'Run unittests'
```

I have gone through the spark github repo and looked in `pyspark` directory, in which there is a `testing` folder.

Furthermore, I had a look at the `setup.py``and I see the following:

```
setup(
        name="pyspark",
        version=VERSION,
        description="Apache Spark Python API",
        long_description=long_description,
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        author="Spark Developers",
        author_email="dev@spark.apache.org",
        url="https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python",
        packages=[
            "pyspark",
            "pyspark.cloudpickle",
            "pyspark.mllib",
            "pyspark.mllib.linalg",
            "pyspark.mllib.stat",
            "pyspark.ml",
            "pyspark.ml.linalg",
            "pyspark.ml.param",
            "pyspark.ml.torch",
            "pyspark.sql",
            "pyspark.sql.avro",
            "pyspark.sql.connect",
            "pyspark.sql.connect.proto",
            "pyspark.sql.pandas",
            "pyspark.sql.protobuf",
            "pyspark.sql.streaming",
            "pyspark.streaming",
            "pyspark.bin",
            "pyspark.sbin",
            "pyspark.jars",
            "pyspark.pandas",
            "pyspark.pandas.data_type_ops",
            "pyspark.pandas.indexes",
            "pyspark.pandas.missing",
            "pyspark.pandas.plot",
            "pyspark.pandas.spark",
            "pyspark.pandas.typedef",
            "pyspark.pandas.usage_logging",
            "pyspark.python.pyspark",
            "pyspark.python.lib",
            "pyspark.data",
            "pyspark.licenses",
            "pyspark.resource",
            "pyspark.errors",
            "pyspark.errors.exceptions",
            "pyspark.examples.src.main.python",
        ],
```

No test module (I'm not sure in what way the `setup.py` affects the modules).

Please let me know if you know more about this, because I would really like to be able to use `pyspark.testing`.

```
import pyspark
logging.warn(dir(pyspark))
```

gives

```
WARNING:root:['Accumulator', 'AccumulatorParam', 'Any', 'BarrierTaskContext', 'BarrierTaskInfo', 'BasicProfiler', 'Broadcast', 'CPickleSerializer', 'Callable', 'HiveContext', 'InheritableThread', 'MarshalSerializer', 'Optional', 'Profiler', 'RDD', 'RDDBarrier', 'Row', 'SQLContext', 'SparkConf', 'SparkContext', 'SparkFiles', 'SparkJobInfo', 'SparkStageInfo', 'StatusTracker', 'StorageLevel', 'TaskContext', 'TypeVar', 'Union', '_F', '_NoValue', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_globals', 'accumulators', 'broadcast', 'cast', 'cloudpickle', 'conf', 'context', 'copy_func', 'errors', 'files', 'filterwarnings', 'find_spark_home', 'inheritable_thread_target', 'java_gateway', 'join', 'keyword_only', 'ml', 'profiler', 'rdd', 'rddsampler', 'resource', 'resultiterable', 'serializers', 'shuffle', 'since', 'sql', 'statcounter', 'status', 'storagelevel', 'taskcontext', 'traceback_utils', 'types', 'util', 'version', 'wraps']
```

so indeed there is no tests, but I don't understand why. Whereas on `Databricks` it gives:

```
WARNING:root:['Accumulator', 'AccumulatorParam', 'Any', 'BarrierTaskContext', 'BarrierTaskInfo', 'BasicProfiler', 'Broadcast', 'CPickleSerializer', 'Callable', 'HiveContext', 'InheritableThread', 'MarshalSerializer', 'Optional', 'PipelinedRDD', 'Profiler', 'ProfilerCollector', 'RDD', 'RDDBarrier', 'Row', 'SQLContext', 'SparkConf', 'SparkContext', 'SparkFiles', 'SparkJobInfo', 'SparkStageInfo', 'StatusTracker', 'StorageLevel', 'TaskContext', 'TypeVar', 'Union', '_F', '_NoValue', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_globals', '_instrument_after_spark_context_init', 'accumulators', 'broadcast', 'cast', 'cloudpickle', 'conf', 'context', 'copy_func', 'databricks', 'errors', 'files', 'filterwarnings', 'find_spark_home', 'inheritable_thread_target', 'instrumentation_utils', 'java_gateway', 'join', 'keyword_only', 'ml', 'mllib', 'pandas', 'profiler', 'rdd', 'rddsampler', 'resource', 'resultiterable', 'serializers', 'shuffle', 'since', 'sql', 'statcounter', 'status', 'storagelevel', 'streaming', 'taskcontext', 'testing', 'traceback_utils', 'types', 'util', 'version', 'wraps']
```

So there it is a module. In both cases `print(pyspark.__version__)`
prints `3.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by just downloading pyspark.testing source and putting it in my own repo ;)